# Magento Payment Method database installer

Tags: database, magento, payment

I'm creating a new payment method for Magento but I get an error when submitting the final order, something like "Cannot save Payment Method" in  popup window. I believe the SQL adjustments have not been made correctly, problem however is that the script I used to built this on uses the following script to alter the database:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("

ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/quote_payment')}` ADD `payment_with` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ;

ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/order_payment')}` ADD `payment_with` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ;

");
$installer->endSetup();
```

As there is no database table called 'sales' I don't really know where to look for the changes that this script makes.

What database table is it adjusting?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Never mind, found the tables.
Are:
 - sales_flat_quote_payment
 - and sales_flat_order_payment

Although sales_flat_order_payment doesn't seem to exist in Magento 1.4.0.1. Might be the problem in general :)